# Unterschied zwischen sichergehen und sorgen

Tags: grammar, difference

> Ich will sichergehen, dass er jeden Tag in die Schule geht.
>
> Ich will dafür sorgen, dass er jeden Tag in die Schule geht

Kann man sie austauschbar verwenden?

Answer (score 1):

Der Duden bietet als Synonym zu *sichergehen* an: *Sich Gewissheit verschaffen*, das deckt sich mit meiner Erwartung, dass hier auch nur eine Überwachung gemeint sein kann, oder etwa, bei einem Lehrer oder Mitschüler nachzufragen.

(Das ist ein rein theoretisches Szenario; tatsächlich sind die Schulen [zumindest in Bayern] verpflichtet, bei Nichterscheinen eines Schülers telefonisch nachzufragen.)

*Dafür sorgen* ist ein aktives Kümmern, sei es das Kind zu wecken und zur Tür zu bringen oder gar bis zur Schultür.